# how do I resolve 400 error code on deploy to nexus?

Tags: maven, nexus3

I am deploying an artifact to a Nexus repository installed on a Windows machine on the same subnet. The nexus server is OSS 3.29.2-02. maven show the following version info:

```
% mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /usr/local/maven/apache-maven-3.6.3
Java version: 15.0.2, vendor: Azul Systems, Inc., runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-15.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.15.7", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

For every deploy that I attempt from any of my 5 artifacts, I get messages similar to the following:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8:deploy (default-deploy) on project home-parent: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact ws.daley.home:home-parent:pom:0.0.1-20210216.155242-17 from/to pihome (http://lemon:8081/repository/pihome/): Transfer failed for http://lemon:8081/repository/pihome/ws/daley/home/home-parent/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/home-parent-0.0.1-20210216.155242-17.pom 400 Bad Request -> [Help 1]
```

If I then download the errant file I get:

```
% curl -X GET http://lemon:8081/repository/pihome/ws/daley/home/home-parent/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/home-parent-0.0.1-20210216.155242-17.pom
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0-M1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ws.daley.home</groupId>
    <artifactId>home-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>home-parent</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>30.1-jre</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.paho</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.8</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-deploy</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <serverId>nexus</serverId>
                    <nexusUrl>http://lemon:8081/repository/pihome/</nexusUrl>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <release>15</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>pihome</id>
            <name>PiHome</name>
            <url>http://lemon:8081/repository/pihome/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>pihome</id>
            <url>http://lemon:8081/repository/pihome/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
<!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId> <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.1</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId> <version>5.7.1</version> </dependency>
    <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId> <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.1</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-migrationsupport</artifactId> <version>5.7.1</version>
    </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId> <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.1</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId> <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId> <artifactId>junit-platform-console</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.1</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId> <version>1.7.1</version> </dependency>
    <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId> <artifactId>junit-platform-jfr</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.1</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId> <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId> <artifactId>junit-platform-reporting</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.1</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId> <version>1.7.1</version> </dependency>
    <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId> <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.1</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-testkit</artifactId> <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId> <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.1</version> </dependency> -->
```

When I look at the Nexus log I do see the 400 error. The following things are kind of strange:

1. Every deploy to the Nexus server fails
2. I only get a failure for the POM file
3. The POM file was actually stored properly verified both by downloading the file and by browsing the artifact on the Nexus web interface.

Is there a resolution for this issue? I know the deploy is successful, but the resulting error causes maven failures which have to be checked each time.

-------------------------- Addendum 1 ------------------------
Here's the console snippet from a mvn -X deploy. I see no evidence of multiple deploys

```
[INFO] --- nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8:deploy (default-deploy) @ home-parent ---
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8:deploy from plugin realm ClassRealm[extension>org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8, parent: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@55054057]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8:deploy' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) artifact = ws.daley.home:home-parent:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]   (f) attachedArtifacts = []
[DEBUG]   (f) autoDropAfterRelease = true
[DEBUG]   (f) autoReleaseAfterClose = false
[DEBUG]   (f) detectBuildFailures = true
[DEBUG]   (f) mavenSession = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@252a8aae
[DEBUG]   (f) mojoExecution = org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8:deploy {execution: default-deploy}
[DEBUG]   (f) nexusUrl = http://lemon:8081/repository/pihome/
[DEBUG]   (f) offline = false
[DEBUG]   (f) packaging = pom
[DEBUG]   (f) pluginArtifactId = nexus-staging-maven-plugin
[DEBUG]   (f) pluginGroupId = org.sonatype.plugins
[DEBUG]   (f) pluginVersion = 1.6.8
[DEBUG]   (f) pomFile = /Users/tim.daley/AixNPanes/HomeServer/home-parent/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) serverId = nexus
[DEBUG]   (f) sslAllowAll = false
[DEBUG]   (f) sslInsecure = false
[DEBUG]   (f) stagingProgressPauseDurationSeconds = 3
[DEBUG]   (f) stagingProgressTimeoutMinutes = 5
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Parameters{pluginGav='org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8', deferredDirectoryRoot=/Users/tim.daley/AixNPanes/HomeServer/home-parent/target/nexus-staging/deferred, stagingDirectoryRoot=/Users/tim.daley/AixNPanes/HomeServer/home-parent/target/nexus-staging/staging, nexusUrl='http://lemon:8081/repository/pihome/', serverId='nexus', keepStagingRepositoryOnCloseRuleFailure=false, keepStagingRepositoryOnFailure=false, skipStagingRepositoryClose=false, autoReleaseAfterClose=false, autoDropAfterRelease=true, stagingProfileId='null', stagingRepositoryId='null', stagingActionMessages=org.sonatype.nexus.maven.staging.StagingActionMessages@f25f48a, tags=null, stagingProgressTimeoutMinutes=5, stagingProgressPauseDurationSeconds=3, sslInsecure=false, sslAllowAll=false}
[DEBUG] Parameters{pluginGav='org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8', deferredDirectoryRoot=/Users/tim.daley/AixNPanes/HomeServer/home-parent/target/nexus-staging/deferred, stagingDirectoryRoot=/Users/tim.daley/AixNPanes/HomeServer/home-parent/target/nexus-staging/staging, nexusUrl='http://lemon:8081/repository/pihome/', serverId='nexus', keepStagingRepositoryOnCloseRuleFailure=false, keepStagingRepositoryOnFailure=false, skipStagingRepositoryClose=false, autoReleaseAfterClose=false, autoDropAfterRelease=true, stagingProfileId='null', stagingRepositoryId='null', stagingActionMessages=org.sonatype.nexus.maven.staging.StagingActionMessages@f25f48a, tags=null, stagingProgressTimeoutMinutes=5, stagingProgressPauseDurationSeconds=3, sslInsecure=false, sslAllowAll=false}
[INFO] Performing deferred deploys (gathering into "/Users/tim.daley/AixNPanes/HomeServer/home-parent/target/nexus-staging/deferred")...
[INFO] Installing /Users/tim.daley/AixNPanes/HomeServer/home-parent/pom.xml to /Users/tim.daley/AixNPanes/HomeServer/home-parent/target/nexus-staging/deferred/ws/daley/home/home-parent/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/home-parent-0.0.1-20210216.205205-19.pom
[DEBUG] Installing ws.daley.home:home-parent:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml to /Users/tim.daley/AixNPanes/HomeServer/home-parent/target/nexus-staging/deferred/ws/daley/home/home-parent/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata-nexus.xml
[DEBUG] Installing ws.daley.home:home-parent/maven-metadata.xml to /Users/tim.daley/AixNPanes/HomeServer/home-parent/target/nexus-staging/deferred/ws/daley/home/home-parent/maven-metadata-nexus.xml
[INFO] Deploying remotely...
[INFO] Bulk deploying locally gathered artifacts from directory:
[INFO]  * Bulk deploying locally gathered snapshot artifacts
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for http://lemon:8081/repository/pihome/
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for http://lemon:8081/repository/pihome/ with username=admin, password=***
Downloading from pihome: http://lemon:8081/repository/pihome/ws/daley/home/home-parent/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded from pihome: http://lemon:8081/repository/pihome/ws/daley/home/home-parent/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (603 B at 46 kB/s)
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file /Users/tim.daley/.m2/repository/ws/daley/home/home-parent/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/resolver-status.properties
Uploading to pihome: http://lemon:8081/repository/pihome/ws/daley/home/home-parent/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/home-parent-0.0.1-20210216.205205-19.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.766 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-16T15:52:07-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8:deploy (default-deploy) on project home-parent: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact ws.daley.home:home-parent:pom:0.0.1-20210216.205205-19 from/to pihome (http://lemon:8081/repository/pihome/): Transfer failed for http://lemon:8081/repository/pihome/ws/daley/home/home-parent/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/home-parent-0.0.1-20210216.205205-19.pom 400 Bad Request -> [Help 1]
```

Here's the Nexus log for the action:

```
10.0.0.113 - admin [16/Feb/2021:12:51:48 -0800] "PUT /repository/pihome/ws/daley/home/home-parent/maven-metadata.xml HTTP/1.1" 201 284 0 62 "Apache-Maven/3.6.3 (Java 15.0.2; Mac OS X 10.15.7)" [qtp1126578142-864]
10.0.0.113 - admin [16/Feb/2021:12:51:48 -0800] "PUT /repository/pihome/ws/daley/home/home-parent/maven-metadata.xml.sha1 HTTP/1.1" 201 40 0 110 "Apache-Maven/3.6.3 (Java 15.0.2; Mac OS X 10.15.7)" [qtp1126578142-860]
10.0.0.113 - admin [16/Feb/2021:12:51:48 -0800] "PUT /repository/pihome/ws/daley/home/home-parent/maven-metadata.xml.md5 HTTP/1.1" 201 32 0 62 "Apache-Maven/3.6.3 (Java 15.0.2; Mac OS X 10.15.7)" [qtp1126578142-864]
10.0.0.113 - - [16/Feb/2021:12:51:48 -0800] "GET /repository/pihome/ws/daley/home/home-parent/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml HTTP/1.1" 200 - 603 0 "Apache-Maven/3.6.3 (Java 15.0.2; Mac OS X 10.15.7)" [qtp1126578142-860]
10.0.0.113 - - [16/Feb/2021:12:51:48 -0800] "GET /repository/pihome/ws/daley/home/home-parent/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.sha1 HTTP/1.1" 200 - 40 0 "Apache-Maven/3.6.3 (Java 15.0.2; Mac OS X 10.15.7)" [qtp1126578142-864]
10.0.0.113 - admin [16/Feb/2021:12:51:48 -0800] "PUT /repository/pihome/ws/daley/home/home-parent/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/home-parent-0.0.1-20210216.205149-18.pom HTTP/1.1" 400 6784 0 15 "Apache-Maven/3.6.3 (Java 15.0.2; Mac OS X 10.15.7)" [qtp1126578142-860]
10.0.0.113 - - [16/Feb/2021:12:52:03 -0800] "GET /repository/pihome/ws/daley/home/home-parent/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml HTTP/1.1" 200 - 603 0 "Apache-Maven/3.6.3 (Java 15.0.2; Mac OS X 10.15.7)" [qtp1126578142-893]
10.0.0.113 - - [16/Feb/2021:12:52:03 -0800] "GET /repository/pihome/ws/daley/home/home-parent/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.sha1 HTTP/1.1" 200 - 40 0 "Apache-Maven/3.6.3 (Java 15.0.2; Mac OS X 10.15.7)" [qtp1126578142-864]
10.0.0.113 - admin [16/Feb/2021:12:52:03 -0800] "PUT /repository/pihome/ws/daley/home/home-parent/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/home-parent-0.0.1-20210216.205205-19.pom HTTP/1.1" 201 6784 0 31 "Apache-Maven/3.6.3 (Java 15.0.2; Mac OS X 10.15.7)" [qtp1126578142-893]
10.0.0.113 - admin [16/Feb/2021:12:52:03 -0800] "PUT /repository/pihome/ws/daley/home/home-parent/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/home-parent-0.0.1-20210216.205205-19.pom.sha1 HTTP/1.1" 201 40 0 31 "Apache-Maven/3.6.3 (Java 15.0.2; Mac OS X 10.15.7)" [qtp1126578142-864]
10.0.0.113 - admin [16/Feb/2021:12:52:03 -0800] "PUT /repository/pihome/ws/daley/home/home-parent/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/home-parent-0.0.1-20210216.205205-19.pom.md5 HTTP/1.1" 201 32 0 16 "Apache-Maven/3.6.3 (Java 15.0.2; Mac OS X 10.15.7)" [qtp1126578142-893]
10.0.0.113 - admin [16/Feb/2021:12:52:03 -0800] "GET /repository/pihome/ws/daley/home/home-parent/maven-metadata.xml HTTP/1.1" 200 - 284 0 "Apache-Maven/3.6.3 (Java 15.0.2; Mac OS X 10.15.7)" [qtp1126578142-864]
10.0.0.113 - admin [16/Feb/2021:12:52:03 -0800] "GET /repository/pihome/ws/daley/home/home-parent/maven-metadata.xml.sha1 HTTP/1.1" 200 - 40 0 "Apache-Maven/3.6.3 (Java 15.0.2; Mac OS X 10.15.7)" [qtp1126578142-893]
10.0.0.113 - admin [16/Feb/2021:12:52:04 -0800] "PUT /repository/pihome/ws/daley/home/home-parent/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml HTTP/1.1" 201 603 0 1204 "Apache-Maven/3.6.3 (Java 15.0.2; Mac OS X 10.15.7)" [qtp1126578142-864]
10.0.0.113 - admin [16/Feb/2021:12:52:04 -0800] "PUT /repository/pihome/ws/daley/home/home-parent/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.sha1 HTTP/1.1" 201 40 0 78 "Apache-Maven/3.6.3 (Java 15.0.2; Mac OS X 10.15.7)" [qtp1126578142-893]
10.0.0.113 - admin [16/Feb/2021:12:52:05 -0800] "PUT /repository/pihome/ws/daley/home/home-parent/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.md5 HTTP/1.1" 201 32 0 157 "Apache-Maven/3.6.3 (Java 15.0.2; Mac OS X 10.15.7)" [qtp1126578142-864]
10.0.0.113 - admin [16/Feb/2021:12:52:05 -0800] "PUT /repository/pihome/ws/daley/home/home-parent/maven-metadata.xml HTTP/1.1" 201 284 0 140 "Apache-Maven/3.6.3 (Java 15.0.2; Mac OS X 10.15.7)" [qtp1126578142-893]
10.0.0.113 - admin [16/Feb/2021:12:52:05 -0800] "PUT /repository/pihome/ws/daley/home/home-parent/maven-metadata.xml.sha1 HTTP/1.1" 201 40 0 78 "Apache-Maven/3.6.3 (Java 15.0.2; Mac OS X 10.15.7)" [qtp1126578142-864]
10.0.0.113 - admin [16/Feb/2021:12:52:05 -0800] "PUT /repository/pihome/ws/daley/home/home-parent/maven-metadata.xml.md5 HTTP/1.1" 201 32 0 47 "Apache-Maven/3.6.3 (Java 15.0.2; Mac OS X 10.15.7)" [qtp1126578142-893]
10.0.0.113 - - [16/Feb/2021:12:52:05 -0800] "GET /repository/pihome/ws/daley/home/home-parent/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml HTTP/1.1" 200 - 603 0 "Apache-Maven/3.6.3 (Java 15.0.2; Mac OS X 10.15.7)" [qtp1126578142-864]
10.0.0.113 - - [16/Feb/2021:12:52:05 -0800] "GET /repository/pihome/ws/daley/home/home-parent/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.sha1 HTTP/1.1" 200 - 40 0 "Apache-Maven/3.6.3 (Java 15.0.2; Mac OS X 10.15.7)" [qtp1126578142-893]
10.0.0.113 - admin [16/Feb/2021:12:52:05 -0800] "PUT /repository/pihome/ws/daley/home/home-parent/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/home-parent-0.0.1-20210216.205205-19.pom HTTP/1.1" 400 6784 0 15 "Apache-Maven/3.6.3 (Java 15.0.2; Mac OS X 10.15.7)" [qtp1126578142-864]
10.0.0.113 - - [16/Feb/2021:12:52:08 -0800] "POST /service/extdirect/poll/rapture_State_get HTTP/1.1" 200 1138 77 0 "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" [qtp1126578142-894]
10.0.0.113 - - [16/Feb/2021:12:53:09 -0800] "POST /service/extdirect/poll/rapture_State_get HTTP/1.1" 200 1138 77 16 "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" [qtp1126578142-865]
10.0.0.113 - - [16/Feb/2021:12:54:10 -0800] "POST /service/extdirect/poll/rapture_State_get HTTP/1.1" 200 1138 77 0 "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" [qtp1126578142-891]
10.0.0.113 - - [16/Feb/2021:12:55:11 -0800] "POST /service/extdirect/poll/rapture_State_get HTTP/1.1" 200 1138 77 0 "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" [qtp1126578142-891]
```

So it looks like Maven is doing 2 puts. Looks like a maven issue. Here's the section of the pom.xml that I think covers the deploy:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.8</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-deploy</id>
                <phase>deploy</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>deploy</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <serverId>nexus</serverId>
            <nexusUrl>http://lemon:8081/repository/pihome/</nexusUrl>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

So it looks like it might be a problem with the nexus-staging-maven-plugin.

Comment: To me this looks like the process is (for some reason) trying to deploy the POM twice.

Comment: I think you're right. See Addendum 1 above. I assume it's a problem with nexus-staging-maven-plugin. Suggestions?

Comment: I also noticed that the repository id was wrong in the <repository> definition (it was Nexus) and in <snapshotRepository> definition (it was PiHome). My settings.xml has pihome. Changing those didn't change anything.